# GoDaddy Kernel Mode Driver Signing - System error 577

Tags: certificate, signing, code-signing-certificate, windows-kernel, driver-signing

I am new to windows drivers and the signing procedure that's required for production use.

I recently purchased a GoDaddy Driver Signing Certificate and they ensured me that it should be working for kernel mode drivers, however I can not seem to be able to make it work.

After compiling I sign the .cat file with signtool with this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool" sign /n "COMPANY_NAME" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll mydriver.cat
```

This finishes successfully and I verify the certificate with this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool" verify /kp /v mydriver.cat
```

The output of the above commands states that is successful. You can see the output below

```
Verifying: mydriver.cat
Signature Index: 0 (Primary Signature)
Hash of file (sha1): AB24DC3601D29CE37CC2611EDEB7C8E3FBD89D04

Signing Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
    Issued by: Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
    Expires:   Thu Jun 29 19:06:20 2034
    SHA1 hash: 2796BAE63F1801E277261BA0D77770028F20EEE4

        Issued to: Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
        Issued by: Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
        Expires:   Mon Nov 16 03:54:37 2026
        SHA1 hash: 7C4656C3061F7F4C0D67B319A855F60EBC11FC44

            Issued to: <COMPANY_NAME>
            Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
            Expires:   Sat Jul 23 19:23:39 2016
            SHA1 hash: B53404B368EED5A734D332C10702B5D5B5C8E5DE

The signature is timestamped: Sat Jul 25 11:37:02 2015
Timestamp Verified by:
    Issued to: Thawte Timestamping CA
    Issued by: Thawte Timestamping CA
    Expires:   Fri Jan 01 01:59:59 2021
    SHA1 hash: BE36A4562FB2EE05DBB3D32323ADF445084ED656

        Issued to: Symantec Time Stamping Services CA - G2
        Issued by: Thawte Timestamping CA
        Expires:   Thu Dec 31 01:59:59 2020
        SHA1 hash: 6C07453FFDDA08B83707C09B82FB3D15F35336B1

            Issued to: Symantec Time Stamping Services Signer - G4
            Issued by: Symantec Time Stamping Services CA - G2
            Expires:   Wed Dec 30 01:59:59 2020
            SHA1 hash: 65439929B67973EB192D6FF243E6767ADF0834E4

Cross Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Sat Nov 01 15:54:03 2025
    SHA1 hash: 8FBE4D070EF8AB1BCCAF2A9D5CCAE7282A2C66B3

        Issued to: Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
        Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
        Expires:   Sun Aug 27 19:48:23 2023
        SHA1 hash: D9612472EF0F2787E2B2D9E063A06B32FA5E333D

            Issued to: Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
            Issued by: Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
            Expires:   Mon Nov 16 03:54:37 2026
            SHA1 hash: 7C4656C3061F7F4C0D67B319A855F60EBC11FC44

                Issued to: <COMPANY_NAME>
                Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
                Expires:   Sat Jul 23 19:23:39 2016
                SHA1 hash: B53404B368EED5A734D332C10702B5D5B5C8E5DE


Successfully verified: mydriver.cat

Number of files successfully Verified: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0
```

The cross certificate part seems to be good. I noticed from a similar output I found online (which was signed from GlobalSign) that the Signing Certificate Chain also led all the way up to Microsoft Code Verification Root. Could this be the problem? And if so how would I go about fixing that?

Installing the .inf goes smoothly, but when I start the driver using

```
net start mydriver
```

I get the error:

```
System error 577 has occurred.

Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or
software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damage
d, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.
```

If I reboot with driver signing enforcement off the above command works fine and the driver works. I have also checked that files in C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository is also signed the same way after installing them.

Does anyone know why the signing does not work, or how I could go about fixing this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've had problems with GoDaddy certificates in the past. Have you correctly installed the intermediate certificates? Perhaps they need to be included when signing the file?

Comment: Thanks for the help Ashigore. You comment made me study the intermediate certificates which had some sort of dependency issue. I have written a response with the steps that I did to get signing working.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem, thanks to Ashigore for directing me the right direction.

The problem was related to my intermediate certificates. It seemed like my certificate store was messed up where some intermediate certificates did not have a valid path up to a root CA.

I deleted every certificate that was related to my certificate and started from scratch.

Now the path is correct as:

- Microsoft Code Verification Root

  - Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority

    - Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
    - My companies certificate

The Microsoft Code Verification Root was not found at all, and I read somewhere that this certificate is hidden in the kernel somewhere and can not be found be certmgr. However it is possible to install it from microsoft if need be from here http://www.microsoft.com/pki/certs/MicrosoftCodeVerifRoot.crt
I don't think it is necessary tho...

I signed the driver files using these commands:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool" sign /v /ac "Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority.cer" /n "MY COMPANY" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll mydriver.cat
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool" sign /v /ac "Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority.cer" /n "MY COMPANY" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll mydriver.sys
```

New output from verification command:

```
Verifying: mydriver.sys
File is signed in catalog: kaac.cat
Hash of file (sha1): 0AFAFD987F9C4B1D0BCBBD7851C0EA89AEF413C0

Signing Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Sat Nov 01 15:54:03 2025
    SHA1 hash: 8FBE4D070EF8AB1BCCAF2A9D5CCAE7282A2C66B3

        Issued to: Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
        Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
        Expires:   Sun Aug 27 19:48:23 2023
        SHA1 hash: D9612472EF0F2787E2B2D9E063A06B32FA5E333D

            Issued to: Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
            Issued by: Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
            Expires:   Mon Nov 16 03:54:37 2026
            SHA1 hash: 7C4656C3061F7F4C0D67B319A855F60EBC11FC44

                Issued to: MY COMPANY
                Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
                Expires:   Sat Jul 23 19:23:39 2016
                SHA1 hash: B53404B368EED5A734D332C10702B5D5B5C8E5DE

The signature is timestamped: Sat Jul 25 14:14:29 2015
Timestamp Verified by:
    Issued to: Thawte Timestamping CA
    Issued by: Thawte Timestamping CA
    Expires:   Fri Jan 01 01:59:59 2021
    SHA1 hash: BE36A4562FB2EE05DBB3D32323ADF445084ED656

        Issued to: Symantec Time Stamping Services CA - G2
        Issued by: Thawte Timestamping CA
        Expires:   Thu Dec 31 01:59:59 2020
        SHA1 hash: 6C07453FFDDA08B83707C09B82FB3D15F35336B1

            Issued to: Symantec Time Stamping Services Signer - G4
            Issued by: Symantec Time Stamping Services CA - G2
            Expires:   Wed Dec 30 01:59:59 2020
            SHA1 hash: 65439929B67973EB192D6FF243E6767ADF0834E4

Cross Certificate Chain:
    Issued to: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Sat Nov 01 15:54:03 2025
    SHA1 hash: 8FBE4D070EF8AB1BCCAF2A9D5CCAE7282A2C66B3

        Issued to: Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
        Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
        Expires:   Sun Aug 27 19:48:23 2023
        SHA1 hash: D9612472EF0F2787E2B2D9E063A06B32FA5E333D

            Issued to: Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
            Issued by: Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
            Expires:   Mon Nov 16 03:54:37 2026
            SHA1 hash: 7C4656C3061F7F4C0D67B319A855F60EBC11FC44

                Issued to: MY COMPANY
                Issued by: Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority
                Expires:   Sat Jul 23 19:23:39 2016
                SHA1 hash: B53404B368EED5A734D332C10702B5D5B5C8E5DE

Successfully verified: mydriver.sys

Number of files successfully Verified: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0
```